# How to compare type?

Tags: flutter

I am using a function to build items. like below

```
  static List<T> buildOptions<T>(field, context, listener){
    if(!field.containsKey('options'))
      return [];

    if((T is FormBuilderFieldOption)||(T is FormBuilderFieldOption<dynamic>))
      return field['options'].map<T>((dynamic option) {
          return FormBuilderFieldOption(value: option['value'], child: listener.render(option, context, 'name'));
      }).toList<T>();

    if((T is DropdownMenuItem)||(T is DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>))
      return field['options'].map<T>((dynamic option) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(value: option['value'], child: listener.render(option, context, 'name'));
      }).toList<T>();

    return [];
  }
```

It was used here

```
          return new FormBuilderDropdown( ...
            items: FBHelper.buildOptions<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>(field, context, listener),
          );
```

But in the function buildOptions the below always returns false even in debug mode I did see the T is "DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>"

(T is DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>)

Any clue? thanks

Comment: thanks, it works now. I did try the ==, but I got error on T == DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>. while T == DropdownMenuItem works. I also need adjust the toList part, not quite straightful. But it works now. Thanks